# How to get the value from the custom header template to parent component in AG Grid Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am developing an angular application with AG grid. The columns are auto generated at run time. I have a requirement of selecting a particular column and performing next operation.

I created a custom header component with radio button and header name.

```
 <div>
      <input class="form-check-input"
        type="radio" name="headerRadios"
        id="customRadios"
        value="{{ params.displayName }}" (change)="onItemChange($event)"/>
      <label class="form-check-label"
        for="customRadios">
        {{ params.displayName }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

With this, the header in my parent component works fine. All my columns have a radio button and header text.

When the user clicks on the radio button, I need to subscribe to this event in parent component so that I get the column name. How can I achieve that.

I have added (change) event on radio buttons and able to get the value of column in custom component. But no able to get the same back to parent component.

```
export class CustomHeader implements IHeaderAngularComp {
  public params!: IHeaderParams & ICustomerHeaderParams;
  @Output() optionChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onItemChange(value: any) {
    this.params.selectedHeader = value.target.value;
    console.log(this.params.selectedHeader);
    this.optionChanged.emit(this.params.selectedHeader);
  }

  agInit(params: IHeaderParams & ICustomerHeaderParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(params: IHeaderParams) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I need to get this selectedHeader back to home component.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: A simple way is to use a service class for changes in the header component and a subject variable which you can set from the child and parent can subscribe to it and detect changes. Otherwise you would need to see a way to listen to the Output event you have emitted from this custom class to parent.

Comment: Thank you, Shameel. your approach works.

Comment: You are welcome, you can add the glimpse of code implementation in the answers for anybody who comes here in future.